# Update page data

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need your help. I have a problem with updating data on a page. Basically I have a homepage where there is data like "FirstName: ...", "LastName: ..." which are retrieved from the login.

Once the login has been completed, you will automatically be taken to the **Homepage page** each time the app is started.
In this way I retrieve the information on the Homepage page.

*The problem is that the user can modify this data through a form (**ModifyProfile**), and once the data is done they are not updated.*
How can I update them anyway?
Thank you.

**Homepage.js**

```
class HomepageUtente extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {

        }
    }
render() {

    const FirstName = global.utente.data.Person.FirstName;
    const LastName = global.utente.data.Person.LastName;

    return (

        <View style={style.container}>
            <View style={style.page}>
                <Icon name="user-circle" color="#64c7c0" size={70} onPress={() => Actions.yourprofile({ cf: Username } )} />

                <Text
                    style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 20, }}>{"Welcome"}
                </Text>
                <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 20, color: '#64c7c0', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
                    {FirstName} {LastName}
                </Text>
                    <Text style={{ color: '#64c7c0', paddingTop: 20 }} onPress={() => Actions.ModifyProfile({ cf: Username })} >Modify Profile</Text>}

            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
}
```

**ModifyProfile**

```
    export default class ModificaProfilo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
    findUtente(cf) {
      //Search data cf in the db
      //......
  //......
    .then(response => {
      let utente = response.docs[0];
        console.log("Utente: " + utente)
        console.log("Sei qui 1")
        utente.Person.FirstName = this.state.FirstName;
        utente.Person.LastName = this.state.LastName;
          global.utente.db.localdb().put(utente);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    })

}

render() {
  return (
    <View style={style.container}>
      <View style={style.page}>
        <KeyboardAwareScrollView>

          <View style={style.inputContainer}>
            <TextInput
              style={style.inputs}
              placeholder="Name"
              placeholderTextColor="#64c7c0"
              keyboardType="default"
              underlineColorAndroid="grey"
              onChangeText={FirstName =>
                this.setState({ FirstName })
              }
            />
          </View>

          <View style={style.inputContainer}>
            <TextInput
              style={style.inputs}
              placeholder="Surname"
              placeholderTextColor="#64c7c0"
              keyboardType="default"
              underlineColorAndroid="grey"
              onChangeText={LastName => 
                this.setState({ LastName })}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={style.footer}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={[style.button, style.buttonOK]}
              onPress={() => this.findUtente(this.props.cf)}
            >
              <Text style={style.buttonTesto}>Modifica</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
```

Comment: Anyone can help me??

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can do that but you shouldn't. Let's solve it first.

1. The component in `Homepage.js`, we call it `A` ;
2. The component in `ModifyProfile`, we call it `B` ;

You need a reference to component `A`, and then call `A.forceUpdate()`.
It means you add `global.A = this` in `Homepage.js`;
add `global.A.forceUpdate()` in `ModifyProfile` after you get the new data;

---

Why: React Component would reRender only if the state or props of the component changes, that's why you need to call `forceUpdate` to make component `A` reRender again unconditionally.

if your change the `FirstName` by `global.utente.data.Person.FirstName = 'NewName'`,  component `A` can not detect the change event.

---

By the way, you should use a state container like `redux` to help you, rather than a global variable. You can connect `FirstName` as your props.

I recommend [dvajs](https://github.com/dvajs/dva) which is easy to learn, you can just focus on the data and flow, you don't need to care about if a component should update most of the times.

And there is a starter of `dvajs`, you can just run it quickly followed by:
[react-native-dva-starter](https://github.com/nihgwu/react-native-dva-starter)

Forget it if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help. When you talk about a component, what are you referring to?

Comment: Oook, So I should use a component and put on it the variables that I would update?

Comment: I think they are already components now in your files.
You can put all the codes of the two files here, cause I can only see part of them.

Comment: Mmh ok and how i should  reference to component so? I'm a little bit confused

Comment: Saw your code. `class HomepageUtente extends Component `,
I think before that there is an `import { Component } from 'react'`.
So `HomepageUtente` is a component.

Comment: Yes it's right! So i should use HomepageUtente.forceupdate() and add global.homepage = this in homepage.js?

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't. It's not the right way to use React. I think you should use a state container, just like I said in my answer. If you change the data like that, it doesn't make sense to use React or React-Native. 
(BTW, I was warned not to discuss too much in the comments by the website, we can find another place to discuss this problem in detail)

Comment: Installing Redux? It's the only way in your opinion???
Thanks for your help